# How to get the next word in a string?

Tags: c#

I feel pretty foolish for asking a seemingly easy question *Sigh* but for the life of me I cant figure it out.

```
string myString = "10/27/14   TheNextString  DontWantThisString";
```

Assume that the second string is unknown(as in it could be any type of word). How could I get the second word after the last index of the date.

Sorry this Is probably a weird question.

```
var lastLine = line.Substring(idx + "date:".Length + 1, 14);
var lastChar = lastLine.Substring(lastLine.Length-1, 1);
headerName = lastLine.Substring(lastLine.LastIndexOf(lastChar), +1);
```

Heres some of my code for a little context if you will.

Comment: Is it always going to be three words separated by spaces where the first word is a date?

Comment: Split on space and get the second element from the array ?

Comment: @eddie_cat yes It will always be separated by spaces but it could contain more than three words. All I care about is the word directly after the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `String.Split()`.

```
string[] delimiters = new string[] {" "};

string[] words = myString.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Definitely best answer since the number of spaces isn't specified to always be a single space per word

Comment: Just to add, the date might not always be the first thing in the list. In which case, you can use this one liner to pull the word right after the date, regardless of where it is in the string: `myString.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[Array.FindIndex(myString.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), z => DateTime.TryParse(z, out dt)) + 1];`

Answer (score 0):

```
string myString = "10/27/14   TheNextString  DontWantThisString";
var values = Regex.Split(myString , @"\s+");

if (values.Count > 1)
    Console.WriteLine(values[1]);
```

This should work (haven't tested the code, but you get the idea).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you. This splits the string into an array, using a space as the separator, removes any empty matches, and then gets the second item.

```
 myString.Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
String result[] = myString.split(null);
```

result[1] will return what you need.

Answer (score 0):

See: [String.SplitMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
namespace SplitDemo
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var myString = "10/27/14   TheNextString  DontWantThisString";
                var stringArray = myString.Split(default(char[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var word = stringArray[1];
            }
        }
    }
```